# vim: Copy buffer to window

Tags: vim

Note: I may totally be using "window" and "buffer" incorrectly here.

When jumping up/down a callstack, would like to look at both the callsite, and the called-function at the same time, in different windows.

I know I can always open a *new* preview window when jumping to a tag - but I find this creates a lot of windows quick.

I think what I want to do, is either:

- Specify an existing window to open the tag in (ex. window to the left, right, ect)
- Simply "save-off" a buffer by showing the same buffer in another existing window.

I'm also open to better ideas

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For following tags, you basically have three options:

- in the same window, replacing the current buffer `:tag`
- in a split window `:stag`; this will create many new windows, to you need to clean up / minimize
- in the preview window `:ptag`; there's only one preview window per tab page, so this self-manages the windows for you; however, if you further navigate *inside* the preview window, further tag jumps effectively become same-window, i.e. `:ptag` is equivalent to `:tag`.

You can build your workflow from there. One idea that's occurring to me as I write this would be a custom `:AlternateTag` command that performs `:ptag` when in a normal window, but re-assigns the preview window to another window is already in the preview window. This would allow you to toggle between two windows for tag lookups.

```
:command! -bar -count -bang -complete=tag -nargs=? AlternateTag if &previewwindow && winnr('$') && winnr('#') > 0 | setlocal nopreviewwindow | call setwinvar(winnr('#'), '&previewwindow', 1) | endif | <count>ptag <args>
```

Comment: Awesome dude! Thanks! Random question: how would you call ptags with current word? I.e. :ptags <cword> searches for <cword> tag

Comment: Glad I could help. To use the current word, use `:execute 'ptags' expand('<cword>')`

Comment: I guess its something else: `nmap <silent> <c-s-i>` works fine, but changing the last part to `<c-s-]>` makes it do nothing?

Comment: `<C-}>` should be the same as `<C-]>`, Vim currently cannot distinguish between the shifted and unshifted variant if it involves Ctrl and non-alphabetic keys.

Comment: Ah crap - oh well! Well, thank you so much for answering my questions! Youre the best!